# LaTeX Background package doesn't function as I command

Tags: backgrounds

When I'm using background package to do some decorating, however found out the outcome wasn't as I expected.
Here's what I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Black}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\begin{document}
\backgroundsetup{pages=some,contents={- \thepage \ -},placement=center,opacity=0.5,scale=2,angle=0,color=Black}

some text
\newpage
some text
\end{document}
```

When I used overleaf to compile, the first "- 1 -" background is totally opaque. For the second one ("- 2 -"), it's 50% opaque as I set. You can use overleaf to run it if my expression is kind of confusing.

I'm really curious about why these strange things are occurring?

Comment: `%I've defined "Black" previously, not shown here` why post an example no one can run? Please post an example of the problem so people can debug it for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for you guys' suggestions, I now edit the code so that it can run on overleaf now.

Comment: It works fine with pdflatex and lualatex. Are you maybe using xelatex?

Comment: yeah, I used the xelatex. So the only solution may be changing the compiler to pdflatex or lualatex?

Comment: Cause pdflatex sometimes doesn't support some other syntax and I personally use xelatex more, I wonder if it's possible to use xelatex to solve this problem

Comment: I tried your code and added `\lipsum` to put more text on the pages. Compiling with `pdflatex`or `lualatex` results in correctly formatted background on the pages. Compiling with`xelatex` - *however* - gives the error you described. So, I guess it's a `xelatex` error as **samcarter** already stated. My advise would be to switch to using `lualatex`, especially when you use `fontspec` or `unicode-math` already to manage your fonts.

Comment: Thanks for all your guys' comments!